# Why is (AnObject).AField = AValue a syntax error in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, syntax

**EDIT:**  Modified code sample to explicitly declare return type of function.

---

Consider the following minimal example:

```
Class AClass
    Public AField As Integer

    Public Sub New(aField As Integer)
        Me.AField = aField
    End Sub

    Public Function AMethod() As Integer
        Return AField
    End Function
End Class

Module AModule

    Sub Main()

        Dim AnObject As AClass = New AClass(12)

        Dim n As Integer = (AnObject).AField  ' This is fine

        Dim m As Integer = (AnObject).AMethod() ' This is fine

        (AnObject).AField = 8 ' BC30035 Syntax Error

        AnObject.AField = 8 ' This is fine

    End Sub

End Module
```

How does the syntax of VB.NET work that there's a difference between these two cases?  It seems that if we're calling a method, or *reading* a field, the parentheses are allowed, but if we're *writing* a field, they're not.

I've tried looking at the [Visual Basic Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/) but I didn't see anything like a formal grammar.  I've also tried googling this, although it's a bit hard to come up with a good set of search keywords.

---

**UPDATE**

So I've looked over the language grammar that Jimi linked and I'm even more confused -- in particular we have

```
RegularAssignmentStatement  ::=  Expression  Equals  Expression  StatementTerminator

Expression  ::= SimpleExpression  |  MemberAccessExpression  | ...

MemberAccessExpression  ::=
    [ MemberAccessBase  ] Period  IdentifierOrKeyword
        [  OpenParenthesis  Of  TypeArgumentList  CloseParenthesis  ]

MemberAccessBase  ::= Expression  | ...

SimpleExpression  ::= LiteralExpression | 
         ParenthesizedExpression  | 
         SimpleNameExpression |
         ... 

SimpleNameExpression  ::=  Identifier  [  OpenParenthesis  Of  TypeArgumentList  CloseParenthesis  ]

ParenthesizedExpression  ::=  OpenParenthesis  Expression  CloseParenthesis
```

According to this grammar, this *isn't* a syntax error!  To be specific,

- `AnObject` is an Identifier, hence a SimpleNameExpression, hence a Simple Expression, hence an Expression.  (I didn't include the definition of identifiers here, but according to the documentation strings of alphabetic characters definitely qualify.)
- Consequently, `(AnObject)` is a ParenthesizedExpression, hence a SimpleExpression, hence an Expression, hence a MemberAccessBase.
- `AField` is an Identifier.
- Putting these two together, `(AnObject).AField` is a MemberAccessExpression, hence an Expression
- `8` is a LiteralExpression, hence an Expression
- The newline at the end of the line is a StatementTerminator
- As a result, `(AnObject).AField = 8` is a RegularAssignmentStatement, according to this grammar.

So, according to the document, this statement ought to parse!

Comment: Turn Option Strict On, it will be more clear.

Comment: @Jimi: Mind elaborating?  I turned on both `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` and the only thing that changed was that it complained I hadn't declared the return type of `AClass.AMethod`.  Once I added the requisite `As Integer`, I still have the same syntax error without any further information.

Comment: @Jimi: Or do you just mean my code sample would be clearer for others to read?

Comment: I just tried your code and it was specifically the leading parenthesis that was indicated as the syntax error. That seems to suggest that a line cannot start with an opening parenthesis. Without having tried to consider all the possibilities, my guess is that there is no otherwise-valid  line of code you would write that would require starting with an opening parenthesis and allowing it could lead to code that looked valid but did not do as obviously intended. Can you think of any situation that would require it?

Comment: Is this a valid Syntax? `Dim m As Integer = ((((((AnObject)))))).AMethod()`. And this one? `[AnObject].AField = 8`. VB.net has rules in relation to how Identifiers must be declared and the positions that defined characters can take. Parenthesis in some positions are just optional. Somewhere else, like any other not explicitly allowed characters, cause a Syntax Error.

Comment: @Jimi: Well, yes, I know that there is *some* kind of rule, since this code gives a syntax error.  But what is the rule?  Where is it written down?

Comment: [The Microsoft Visual Basic Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15039). (.docx Download) - Chapter 2.2

Comment: In addition to what @Jimi directed you to, also look section "11.4.2 Parenthesized Expressions" - specifically "A parenthesized expression evaluates to the value of the expression within the parentheses.".

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the link.  I looked over the document, but as far as I can see the line in question ought to parse with this grammar -- see the edits to my question.

Comment: @TnTinMn: That's precisely what I'd expect -- `(AnObject)` should evaluate to `AnObject`, and then I should be able to assign something to one of its fields.

Comment: Yep, it doesn’t seem like it should be a syntax error. If you overload the `+` operator and do `(AnObject + AnObject).AField = 8`, does that work?

Comment: Hierarchy in declarations define these bounds. Some rules have precedence over others. Chapter 2 comes before chapter 11, for example.

Comment: @Ry︁: Nope, same error.  Sounds like this tries to parse in some unexpected way, although I'm having trouble spotting it in the grammar.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, The terminology used in the specification is a bit confusing.  For assignment statements the pattern is: `RegularAssignmentStatement  ::=  Expression  Equals  Expression  StatementTerminator`.  The usage of `Expression` has its own definition.  Note that my prior reference stated that the "parenthesized expression evaluates to the **value**".  _Value_ is not the same as _Expression_.  At least that is how I read it.

Comment: @TnTinMn: I excerpted the relevant definitions above.  A ParenthesizedExpression is a kind of Expression.  Jimi seems to be hinting that the grammar is ambiguous and some other rule is taking precedence, but I haven't been able to spot what it is.

Comment: Don’t put too much stock into the VB grammar: it isn’t normative, it used to not even be formal, and was developed as an afterthought.

Comment: I think that it's to do with that on the right hand side, you can do things `(List1.Count -1).ToString` where the code inside the parentheses produces a result which is an integer and you can then convert it to a string all in one line. On the left hand side, you can only have the field/property/object that is being assigned to, so there is no definition for use of brackets on the left. Same as not putting question marks at the beginning of sentences in Uk English. Both are syntax errors :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m purely guessing here but I’d say that this is an artefact of VB’s feature to [force value over reference passing by using parentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-force-an-argument-to-be-passed-by-value):

```
Sub ChangeMe(ByRef x As Integer)
    x += 1
End Sub

Dim x = 1
ChangeMe(x)   ' x = 2
ChangeMe((x)) ' still x = 2
```

In your code, the compiler probably treats `(AnObject)` as a *value* rather than a reference to the original object, determines that an assignment to a field would therefore be discarded, and disallows the assignment.

Of course even when passing `AnObject` to a method by value, modifying `AnObject.Field` would still modify the original object. So, by analogy, the code *should* work. I’m guessing that the VB compiler is applying a faulty heuristic here.

Comment: What's been discussed is the lexical grammar that applies to *Assignments* in this language. A regular assignment is defined in chapert 10.6 of the Language Reference. The syntax of the left part of an assignment is evaluated using the general rules specified in chapter 2.2. So, `Dim i as Interger = 1` `[i]=2` => i = 2. `[i] = ((i) * 2)` => i = 4. Square brackets have a meaning in vb.net, but this meaning does not modify the type or value of `i` in this context. Parenthesis, on the other hand, are used as indexers in vb.net. Used on the left side of an assignment in this way, is a Syntax Error

Comment: In C# `int i;` `((i)) = 1;` => i = 1 while `[i] = 2` => *i does not exits in this context*. vb.net `Dim [Integer] As Integer = 1` is valid, in C# `int [int]`  and `int (int)` are not. Each compiler enforces the rules in relation to the language requirements. In assignments, vb.net can appear more strict than it usually seems to be, because the assignment operator and the equality comparer are the same, so the rules that apply to the Identifiers/Variables classification and identification are not free-form.

Comment: @Jimi Sorry, I don’t understand your comments entirely. You’re right about the overloading of the meaning of the `=` operator. I *don’t think* that’s the problem here but it might well be.

Comment: The double meaning of the `=` operator implies that the actual use must be interpreted. The interpretation process implies that the rules that define what's on the left-hand of the operator have to be enforced more strictly than one might think (mainly because a number of vb.net programmer do not use Option Strict/Explicit). The parenthesis are used as indexers. If their presence is not otherwise justified in that context, it can't be assumed that they're there for *fancy* reasons. The ambiguity in interpretation is better (missing indexed element?) resolved with a Syntax Error.

Comment: @Jimi Right. Well I don’t know the internals of the VB parser but I highly doubt that the above runs into the code path for indexers. The way most parsers work, the indexer code path would only trigger if the left-hand preceding tokens (left-hand side of the indexer expression) make this possible. But this isn’t the case here. This will almost certainly be parsed as a ‹ParenthesizedExpression›.

Comment: It could. In C# it does. But there's no rule in vb.net for `ParenthesizedExpression` on the left-hand of an assignment. Parethesis only applies to methods and indexed elements. And none of those are found. So, fall back to naming conventions for Identifiers. Parenthesis are not in the allowed unicode characters list. So, what to do? One can argue that they look cool, but, bummer, rules are rules :)

Comment: @Jimi: According to the official document you linked, there *is* a rule in VB.NET for `Expression` on the left-hand side of an assignment, and a `ParenthesizedExpression` is an `Expression`.  If you're aware of something beyond the official documentation, I wish you'd share it with the rest of us.